# QSqlDatabase lastError() returns empty string for error in query

Tags: sql, sqlite, qt, qsqldatabase

I was writing simple code using SQLite database in Qt:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(id, name)");
// ... adding data here
if(query.exec("SELECT * from test")) {
    while(query.next()) {
        qDebug() << query.value(0).toString();
    }
} else {
    qDebug() << "Error: " << db.lastError().text();
}
```

and noticed, that I get empty string instead of error text, if I make some mistake in query (for example, misspell table name - `"SELECT * from tesst"`). So, why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, for catching query errors, I should be using `query.lastError().text()` instead of `db.lastError().text()`

Comment: Press answer button (Tik icon below down vote) to show this answer solved your problem.

Comment: I can't, it says that I can accept my own answers in 2 days